# Plot raw time series with Kibanan Timelion

Tags: time-series, kibana, timelion

I might not get something. How can I plot a raw time series with Timelion without applying any further aggregation? Just the raw data of a field over time that I have in an index. Of course I select the proper time window for the data.

Comment: That is not possible. Timelion only plots aggregation results. Plotting raw documents is not a scalable solution since your browser can only handle so many points before following over. Try using [Vega visualization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.2/vega-quick-demo.html) to create a scattor plot or [Kibana Canvas](https://canvas.elastic.co/)

Comment: Thanks Natan, seems to be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve the same thing, but didn't fully get what I wanted, but maybe these steps will help you.

- My data was on by minute basis, so I don't want any more frequent fragmentation. Selecting interval = 1m helps only for short periods of time, but adding "interval=1m" into .es() block works on long periods, too.
- To have lines not to return to 0 in between points, use .es().fit(carry)
- .es().scale_interval(1m).fit(scale) - this is my chart to return to 0 if there were no data for certain period rather than carrying the line on the same level.
- .es(metric=max:value_field) helps not to sum up the values, but show the max of the aggregated set.

My charts are still weirdly aggregated, but maybe it'll help someone.

Useful links:
Sparse time series in timelion
https://www.elastic.co/blog/sparse-timeseries-and-timelion

Scaling issue 1
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/diferent-value-on-y-axis-depending-on-time-interval/67785

Scaling issue 2
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/timelion-giving-wrong-metric-aggregate-value-on-enlarging/132789

Scaling issue 3
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/re-timelion-giving-wrong-metric-aggregate-value-on-enlarging/132925